# Sails.js: Sending a 409 response if a duplicate record is posted

Tags: sails.js

Not sure how to do this in sails.js, but I'd like to be able to, when creating a new object on the API, check to see if that object's id exists and if it does, send a 409 conflict response, and if it doesn't, create the object like normal.

For the sake of discussion, I've created a Brand model.

I'm assuming that I would override the create function in the BrandController, search for the brand based on `req.param('id')` and if it exists, send the error response. But I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly, as I can't seem to get anything to work.

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since this is MVC you are thinking correctly that the Control should be enforcing this logic.  However, as this is basic uniqueness by the primary id the model should know/understand and help enforce this.

1. Model should identity the conflict.

   - In sails the coder is responsible for the defining uniqueness, but I would have the model object do it not the controller.
2. The controller should route/respond by sending the view which is effectively http 409.

   - Yes the controller create method should be used in this case, as sails wants to provide CRUD routes for you.  Assuming it is a logical create not some resultant or odd non-restful side effect.
   - I think of Sails.js by default providing a model controller, so use their perspective since you are using their framework.  There are many approaches to Control/Model relationships.
   - res.view([view, options[, fn]])
3. Ideally the view would control the http response code, the message, any special additional headers.  The view just happens to be extremely basic, but could vary in the future.

   - You could always set headers and response with JSON from the controller but views offer you flexibility in the future, like decoupling, the reason the MVC pattern exists.  However, sails also seems to value convenience, so if it is a small app maybe directly from the controller.

Comment: Thanks, Ted. I'll attempt to turn your advice into code this evening. Once it's done, I'll mark this as the answer and paste in some practical code.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct, but I did paste the code that ended up working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using a policy for this particular use case.

Under `config/policies`, I created a isRecordUnique policy:

```
/**
 * recordIsUnique
 *
 * @module      :: Policy
 * @description :: Simple policy to check that a record is unique
 *               
 * @docs        :: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/policies
 *
 */

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

    Brand.findOne({ id: req.body.id}).done(function (err, brand) {

        if (brand) {
            res.send(409);
        } else {
            next();
        }

    });

};
```

This allowed me to avoid overriding any CRUD functions and it seemed to fit the definition of a policy, in that only checks one thing.

To tie my policy to my create function, I modified `config/policies` by adding:

```
BrandController: {

    create: 'isRecordUnique'

}
```

That's it. Took me way too long to figure this out, but I think it's a good approach.